# Mongo Oplog Tailable Cursor

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

We are using the mongo java driver 3.2.2 and the mongo oplog collection to identify changes in our mongo collections(Mongo server version is 3.2). We are encountering the below 2 issues and have few questions regarding the same. If anyone of you have encountered the same issue(s),please help us in clarifying them.The below issues happen especially when there are heavy write operations in the oplog.

**Code:**

```
MongoCursor<Document> tailableCursor = collection.find(query).sort(new Document("$natural", 1)).cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait).noCursorTimeout(true).iterator();
```

1. **com.mongodb.MongoExecutionTimeoutException: operation exceeded time limit**

   a.) Would setting the maxTime help in handling the exception better?? What would be a practical value for maxTime given that we are using a tailable await cursor? The below link is indicating that for a cursor subsequent "getmore" requests will be included in the total time. 
        https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/maxtimems-and-query-optimizer-introspection-in

   b.) Would using a non blocking cursor call help?? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html#tryNext--

   c.) In case of an exception like above, what is the best way to handle the error gracefully and continue the processing of subsequent records?
2. **com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 96 and error message 'Executor error during find command: CappedPositionLost: CollectionScan died due to position in capped collection being deleted**

   Would increasing the Oplog size help resolve this issue? Are there any other alternative solutions available?

Answer (score 2):

We faced the similar problem for a long time. After some research, We found this official doc is very helpful.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/

Our problem was "replication lag"

> Replication lag is a delay between an operation on the primary and the application of that operation from the oplog to the secondary. Replication lag can be a significant issue and can seriously affect MongoDB replica set deployments. Excessive replication lag makes “lagged” members ineligible to quickly become primary and increases the possibility that distributed read operations will be inconsistent.

Possible causes of replication lag include:

- Network Latency
- Disk Throughput
- Concurrency

> In some cases, long-running operations on the primary can block replication on secondaries. For best results, configure write concern to require confirmation of replication to secondaries. This prevents write operations from returning if replication cannot keep up with the write load.

- Appropriate Write Concern

> If you are performing a large data ingestion or bulk load operation that requires a large number of writes to the primary, particularly with unacknowledged write concern, the secondaries will not be able to read the oplog fast enough to keep up with changes.
>   To prevent this, request write acknowledgement write concern after every 100, 1,000, or another interval to provide an opportunity for secondaries to catch up with the primary.

We followed section "Possible causes of replication lag include" and did two things:

- Rewrite insertion code with appropriate write concerns
- Limit insertion rate

Then our problem was solved.